# android webview open browser window from Javascript

Tags: javascript, android, iframe, webview

I'm including a mobile google advert in a webview (in a fragment). When you click the ad I wanted to open in new browser. I've enabled the following:

```
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
```

The google.js is generating a iFrame with  however clicking the webview doesn't seem to register as a new link click and doesn't call `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer in another so question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5641626/how-to-get-webview-iframe-link-to-launch-the-browser),

However I've modified it to work for a fragment (included getActivity()). **Note this is specifically for google ads**.  In you webclient overide the following method.

```
  @Override
        public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url)
        {
            // the url that contains the ad to link to contains googleads, this is risky if google
            // change it, but there couldn't find a nice way around
            if (url.contains("googleads"))
            {
                HitTestResult hitTestResult = view.getHitTestResult();
                // Check is the hit test is a src tag with image anchor (i.e an mobile ad) 
                if (hitTestResult.getType() == HitTestResult.SRC_IMAGE_ANCHOR_TYPE)
                {
                    getActivity().startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
                    view.stopLoading();                        
                }
            }
        }
```